# mostrar una variable en consulta mysql Inner

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una consulta de varias tablas y estas tienen campos con el mismo nombre.

quisiera saber si hay forma de mostrar el valor de uno de esos campos con el mismo nombre pero seleccionado de cual de las tablas.

normalmente uso $row["id"] pero supongamos que el campo "id" existe en dos tablas que uno con un INNER JOIN como podría mostrar indistintamente el campo "id" de artículos y de Direcciones?

la consulta seria esta:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articulos` art INNER JOIN `Direcciones` ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.id WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 limit 0,20
```

Comment: Compartí la consulta SQL y podremos ayudarte. En estos casos se pueden usar alias para los campos. *SELECT clientes.Nombre as NombreCliente, empleados.Nombre as NombreEmpleado*

Comment: Puesta la consulta @AgustinM. En efecto uso alias, pero lo que yo necesito seria la forma de construir un echo de php que me muestre uno de los campos

Comment: Comprendo pero tu consulta solo trae los resultados de la tabla Articulos con el alias art. Además estás utilizando alias para las Tablas pero yo menciono ponerle un alias a los campos también, lo que hago en *clientes.Nombre as NombreCliente*

Comment: No, trae resultados de todas. por lo menos de los campos que no coinciden. @AgustinM.

Comment: Y como tendría que hacerlo entonces? @AgustinM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT art.id as idart, ean.id as idean,
    /*  las demas columnas que necesitas */ 
   FROM `Articulos` art INNER JOIN `Direcciones` ean 
     ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
                        INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf 
    ON art.sexo = conf.id 
  WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR
        ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 limit 0,20
```

Comment: Con eso defino un solo campo ¿no? no podría hacer un echo tipo $row["idart.nombre"] ósea que tengo que crear todos los alias en la consulta mysql directamente. Por cierto, funciona perfectamente :) Mil gracias

Comment: Killpe, que bueno que te haya servido mi respuesta.
 Te dejo este link (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html) para aclarar tus dudas sobre el uso del  los **alias**